Python giving different response when called via async
Getting different output for the same logic?
Was trying to learn async/await in python.
Output for first Snippet : <class 'dict'>
Output for second Snippet : <class 'list'>

Snippet 1 : without async
import urllib.request
import json

def get_response(user_url):
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(user_url).read()
    resp_json = json.loads(resp)
    return resp_json['results'][0]


def make_request(user_url):
    json_response = get_response(user_url)
    print(type(json_response))

USER_URL = 'https://randomuser.me/api'
make_request(USER_URL)

Snippet 2 : with async
import urllib.request
import json
import asyncio

async def get_response(user_url):
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(user_url).read()
    resp_json = json.loads(resp)
    return resp_json['results'][0]


async def make_request(user_url):
    json_response = await asyncio.gather(get_response(user_url))
    print(type(json_response))

USER_URL = 'https://randomuser.me/api'
asyncio.run(make_request(USER_URL))

Why are we getting different output for the same logic in code?
Expectation is to get dict data type for both.
Using Python 3.10

That <class 'list'> is the return value of the asyncio.gather().

If all awaitables are completed successfully, the result is an aggregate list of returned values. You'll then need to iterate through the list to access the result of the awaitables.

If you only have that single URL, await get_response(user_url) is enough. asyncio.gather() is for executing multiple awaitables concurrently and wait for them to finished.
